# Is there a difference between HDMI or Thunderbolt for monitor?

Tags: hdmi, thunderbolt-display

This is my configuration:

- Samsung S22A300B monitor (with VGA and DVI input)
- Computer A

  - 2,6GHz Mac Mini from end of 2014
  - HDMI to DVI cable
  - Thunderbolt to VGA cable
- Computer B

  - Mac Book (yes, old)
  - output video to DVI cable (forget the connector name)

My problem is:  If I connect the Computer A to VGA, will I lose something in quality? With this configuration I can use booth computer on same monitor, just need to press the switch button. In another configuration, I will need to physically change the cables.

So, Is there a difference if I use Thunderbolt instead HDMI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering straight yes. You loose quality when connecting monitor with VGA.

You see VGA is analog standard and digital signal being first time converted into analog in a computer to be transmitted through VGA cable and then converted back into digital to be used by the digital TFT panel. Since there are few steps of converting signal and analog interference while in a cable you have few chances to loose on quality.

Then it depends on particular setup, cables and quality of convertor when answering how much of quality being lost. So if you don't see that quality is degraded on you VGA connected MacMini compared to MacBook on DVI that it is safe it definitely more convenient to leave them as they are.

Comment: Lol, very good answer. This is not yes or no, but is: most probably yes, I will lose quality. My old mac book don't need this privilege now. I will not use it so often so I will change the cable manually when I need it.